# ¿Como limitar la cantidad de caracteres en un Entry en Python

Tags: python, tkinter

resulta que estoy trabajando con la librería tkinter en python y me surgió la necesidad de limitar la cantidad de caracteres que se puedan ingresar dentro de un entry, he estado buscando como hacerlo pero no encuentro respuesta ojala alguien pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("200x200+50+50") 

zona_c = Canvas(gui, width = 200, height = 200) 
zona_c.config(background="cyan4")
zona_c.pack()

entry_text = StringVar() 
entry_widget = Entry(zona_c, width = 20, textvariable = entry_text,justify=CENTER) 
zona_c.create_window(100, 100, window = entry_widget)

def limitador(entry_text):
    if len(entry_text.get()) > 0:
        #donde esta el :5 limitas la cantidad d caracteres
        entry_text.set(entry_text.get()[:5])

entry_text.trace("w", lambda *args: limitador(entry_text))
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: gracias, de verdad me fue de mucha ayuda tu aporte